# bootstrap confidence interval for random samples

Tags: matlab, statistics, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have a list of 500 data `(y=500)`
I am using bootstrap method in matlab in order to calculate confidence interval.
I am using bootci function,
`bootci(1000,@mean,randsample(y, 50, true))` 
**Normally:** Here the 50 random data is re-sampled(with replacement) 1000 times from the same 50 data. 
**I want:** Can i do something so the 50 data will be re-sampled 1000 times from not fixed 50 random data but from 500(entire) data?

Is there any other function helps to do it? any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
bootci(1000, @(x) mean(randsample(x, 50, true)), y)
```

By moving the resampling inside the `bootfun` you will get a (potentially) new 50-element sample during each bootsrap sampling (1000 times). Furthermore, by specifying `y` as the data argument for `bootci` you achieve that the 500-element (full) data is sampled.